# What is the ORM for Android with support @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)?

Tags: android, orm

I am developing an android chat application, I have several types of messages inherited from a single abstract class. I want to get a list of different types of chat messages. I think I need an ORM with inheritance support with a SINGLE_TABLE strategy. Is there an ORM for Android with support for this functionality? Or, perhaps, you will advise how to solve this problem using the ORM without SINGLE_TABLE support?

Examples:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessage implements MessageListContent, Serializable, Comparable<AbstractMessage> {

    public enum Status {
        DELIVERED,
        SENDING_AND_VALIDATION,
        NOT_SENDED,
        INVALIDATED
    }

    private SupportedMessageListContentType supportedType = SupportedMessageListContentType.UNDEFINED;
    private boolean iSay;
    private long timestamp;
    private Status status = Status.SENDING_AND_VALIDATION;
    private String transactionId;
    private String companionId;

    // getters and setters
    //...
 }

 public class BasicMessage extends AbstractMessage {
    private String text;
    private transient Spanned htmlText;

    // getters and setters
    //...
}

public class TransferMessage extends AbstractMessage {
    private BigDecimal amount;

    // getters and setters
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you know a lot about ORM's in android, but, two of the most famous ORM's for Android are Room and Realm. And these two could achieve what you want. But, don't take my word on realm, as I am only going to state what my friend told me about realm.

For starters, Room runs in SQLite and Realm in NoSQL. Now, I assume that you know greatly about inheritance and polymorphism, this *concept* could also be applied to SQL. This is, taking in account that you choose SQLite. Now for realm, it is a different story tho. My friend told me that the polymorphism of your models answers to the polymorphism of the database. Though, ***I highly doubt that***, but I don't like realm, so don't take my word for it.

For choosing your database, I will be frank to tell you to choose SQLite and to help you decide, here is a simple site that currated reasons on which is better, SQL or NoSQL: http://www.nosql-vs-sql.com/